# How to obtain multiple Email addresses for API testing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email, testing

Before you read this question, I apologize for not being fluent in English. I hope for your understanding.

I'm a front-end developer using React, currently working on implementing the Sign-Up function.
To achieve this, I need to connect to the Sign-up API and Email-verify API.

During the testing phase of these APIs, I require email addresses.
However, once an email is used for testing the API, it becomes unavailable for further use as the account is already registered and verified.
So, to test APIs many times, I need many email addresses.

Is there a way to obtain multiple emails for testing APIs?
Can I use temporary or virtual email addresses for testing purposes?

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is thinking in the way of such..."mock/fake, generated emails"?

If so, you have options.

One of the biggest ones that comes to mind for me is testmail.app, you have unlimited emails (depending on your plan, but it is free for 100).

They have a decent JSON/GraphQL API for email querying with CI/CD pipelines.

If you want basic, generated emails, try MailHog or Mockaroo. I've used them before for other purposes of generation/testing.

MailHog is my preferred option here. Sets up a fake SMTP server that you can locally test emails with.

Comment: Feels like Postman should have something that provides temporary mock email addresses.

Comment: @Sintrias, I wish it did. If he were to want to use Postman as an environment (which I wouldn't recommend for this purpose), he would need to integrate a third party.

Answer (score 3):

You can use email plus addressing.
It gives you access to unlimited email addresses based off your one single email account.

1. jason+welcome1@example.com.
2. jason+welcome2@example.com.
3. jason+welcome3@example.com.

All of these will go to jason@example.com

Comment: This will definitely work in Gmail. I have used similar in the past

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure that I work for the company, but this is what dedicated services like [Mailosaur](https://mailosaur.com/) provide. Unlimited email addresses to test with and an API to intercept emails, test them, etc.

There are free/non-commercial alternatives that do similar, so it can depend on scale/importance of data security to you/your company, etc. as to whether you need a full service solution.